# how to add a list of value in case of same key for hashmap in groovy

Tags: list, groovy, hashmap

A need to associate the list of values for specific keys

for example,

```
​listTags= ['A:1.1.1.1', 'B:1.1.2.1', 'C:1.1.3.1', 'B:1.1.4.1']

tags = [ : ]

listTags.each { it ->

  tags.put(it.split(':')[0], it.split(':')[1] )

}

println tags
```

Result: `[A:1.1.1.1, B:1.1.4.1, C:1.1.3.1]`

Expected Result: `[A:1.1.1.1, B:[1.1.2.1, 1.1.4.1] , C:1.1.3.1]`

Any suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use inject for this.

Here, we split all strings in the list and then starting with an empty map, append the values to a list for each key

```
​listTags= ['A:1.1.1.1', 'B:1.1.2.1', 'C:1.1.3.1', 'B:1.1.4.1']

def result = listTags*.split(':')
    .inject([:].withDefault {[]}) { m, v ->
      m[v[0]] << v[1]
      m
    }​​​
```

Comment: It works fine from groovy enterpreter but not as a part of jenkins pipeline:
spread not yet supported for CPS transformation @ line 98, column 22.
     def result = listTags*.split(':'). Any suggestion?

Comment: try replacing `listTags*.split(':')` with `listTags.collect { it.split(':') }`